# Read JSON-file into environment variable with Docker Compose

Tags: json, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've dockerized a Meteor-app with [Meteord](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord), and that works fine, my problem is that I want to pass some settings to the app.

Meteord does not start the app with a settings-file as one would usually do to give settings to an app (`meteor --settings file.json`). This is also possible to do [with an environement variable](http://joshowens.me/environment-settings-and-security-with-meteor-js/)  called `METEOR_SETTINGS`.

As I want the webapp to run with other services, I'm using Docker Compose.

I have my `settings.json`-file that I want to be read in as a environment variable, so something like:

```
  environment:
   - METEOR_SETTINGS=$cat(settings.json)
```

This doesn't work though.

How can I make Docker compose dynamically create this environment variable based on a JSON-file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible without some trickery, depending on the amount of tweakable variables in `settings.json`:

If it's a lot of settings it's fairly easy to template the `docker-compose.yml` with a simple shell script that replaces a token in the template with the contents of `settings.json`, much like in your example. You also want to wrap the docker-compose call in that case. Simplified example:

*docker-compose.yml.template*:

```
environment:
 - METEOR_SETTINGS=##_METEOR_SETTINGS_##
```

*dc.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh
# replace ##_METEOR_SETTINGS_## with contents of settings.json and output to docker-compose.yml
sed -e 's|##_METEOR_SETTINGS_##|'"$(cat ./settings.json)"'|' \
    "./docker-compose.yml.template" > "./docker-compose.yml"
# wrap docker-compose, passing all arguments
docker-compose "$@"
```

Put the 2 files into your project root, then `chmod +x dc.sh` to make the wrapper executable and call `./dc.sh -h`.

If it's only a few settings you could handle the templating *inside* the container when its starting. Simply replace tokens placed in a prepared `settings.json` with ENV values passed to docker before starting Meteor. This allows you to just use the docker-compose ENV features to configure Meteor.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by wrapping the docker-compose call, and could you provide an example of the templating technique with a shell script in your answer?

Comment: I updated the answer, untested but should get you going.

Comment: The only problem with this is that I found Meteor does not have access to environment variables built in, so you have to go via Node. My solution was to paste the JSON-settings into a `METEOR_SETTINGS` variable in an [`env`-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), but I recommend adjusting this suggested scriped if one has many settings variables, so that the script creates the `env`-file for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not portable.

Answer (score 8):

An easy way to do this is to load the JSON file in to a local env var, then use that in your yaml file.

In docker-compose.yml

```yaml
environment:
  METEOR_SETTINGS: ${METEOR_SETTINGS}
```

Load the settings file before invoking docker-compose:

```sh
❯ METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat settings.json) docker-compose up
```